# Symfony 3 - The identifier id is missing for a query of AppBundle\Entity\User

Tags: symfony

I am a novice in development.

I want use this script : **https://github.com/sebtouze/LoupGarou**.
I followed the steps well, but I get an error:

> Doctrine\ORM\ORMException: The identifier id is missing for a query of
>   AppBundle\Entity\User at n/a
>       in C:\UwAmp\www\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\ORMException.php
>   line 294
>
> at
>   Doctrine\ORM\ORMException::missingIdentifierField('AppBundle\Entity\User',
>   'id')
>       in C:\UwAmp\www\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php
>   line 403
>
> at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->find('AppBundle\Entity\User',
>   array('id' => null), null, null)
>       in C:\UwAmp\www\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php
>   line 154
>
> at Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->find(null)
>       in C:\UwAmp\www\src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 189
>
> at AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController->indexAction('public')
>       in C:\UwAmp\www\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php
>   line 135
>
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request),
>   '1')
>       in C:\UwAmp\www\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php
>   line 57
>
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request),
>   '1', true)
>       in C:\UwAmp\www\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php
>   line 67
>
> at
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request),
>   '1', true)
>       in C:\UwAmp\www\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php
>   line 183
>
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
>       in C:\UwAmp\www\web\app.php line 28

[Error in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR7o5.png)

Can you help me please ?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: You must test the contents of your variables. Here, a variable that should contain an id is in fact null.

Answer (score 2):

An entity is not an array and cannot be queried as such. It is an object.

At line(s) 189 (and 193), instead of:

```
$vote = $userRepository->find($vote['id']);
```

try:

```
$vote = $userRepository->find($vote->getId());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have answer in your post

`DefaultController.php line 189` you passed variable that is null. Check the variables that are passed there especially `id` I can't say more because I don't see the code you posted only error.

Comment: I don't find where the problem comes from, here is the file DefaultController.php : https://pastebin.com/48G0uFEX Thank!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned your error is here (DefaultController.php line 189):

```
foreach($arraySynthesisMayorVotes as $vote)
{
    $vote = $userRepository->find($vote['id']);
}
```

You're going through a foreach and overwriting $vote over and over.  It's also the same variable you're passing into with your foreach.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code block is culprit. I couldnt make any sense of this code block. I think you need to change it or remove it

```
$userRepository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
foreach($arraySynthesisMayorVotes as $vote)
{
        $vote = $userRepository->find($vote['id']);
}
foreach($arraySynthesisVillageVotes as $vote)
{
        $vote = $userRepository->find($vote['id']);
}
```

If you wanted to count total votes, you can use `count($arraySynthesisVillageVotes)`. But it depends upon your business logic